# Can I clone an existing OS X install into a virtual machine on a Windows 7 PC?

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, virtualbox, virtual-machine

So I have a Macbook Pro running OS X Mavericks. I just built a Windows 7 PC.

Is there anyway I can effectively 'clone' my OS X machine and put it into a VM that I can run on my Windows 7 PC?

That way I can access all my programs and such, just as I would on my MBP.

I don't need to sync the VM to the real machine or anything.

I just want to be able to work within my existing OS X setup from my desktop without having to start from scratch.

Is that possible? If so, how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-install-os-x-mavericks-hackintosh-on-pc-tutorial/

If you can get that working in Virtualbox, you still don't have the same desktop, but copying your user folder is not that complicated.

To answer your question - without starting from scratch: I don't think that is possible. On the other hand, if you have this working, and if you are smart with using snapshots after each install step, you can update the system quite easily. Document what you do so you can reproduce the steps next year without inventing the wheel one more time.